# How can I do multiple operations inside a C# LINQ ForEach loop

Tags: c#

I have a list of Question objects and I use a `ForEach` to iterate through the list. For each object I do an `.Add` to add it into my entity framework and then the database.

```
List<Question> add = problem.Questions.ToList();
add.ForEach(_obj => _uow.Questions.Add(_obj));
```

I need to modify each of the objects in the `ForEach` and set the  `AssignedDate` field to `DateTime.Now`. Is there a way I can do this inside of the `ForEach` loop?

Comment: Just use a plain old `foreach` statement. Unless you have specific reason to use a lambda, which is very unlikely, you are making this unnecessarily complex.

Comment: You can `_obj => { bunch of operations }` but I don't recommend it. Simple foreach is much cleaner

Comment: Well I was just hoping there would be a way as I could maybe use that later. The ForEach looks very clean and I just learned about that recently.

Comment: @Melina: No, actually it looks messy. The benefit is that you can configure the operation to be executed on each question at runtime, but if you don't make use of this benefit you are just left with messy. I think you are suffering from a case where you just learned about something and you want to use it everywhere.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You would do something like

```
add.ForEach(_obj =>
                {
                    _uow.Questions.Add(_obj);
                    Console.WriteLine("TADA");
                });
```

Have a look at the examples in [Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

> The following example demonstrates the use of the Action delegate
>   to print the contents of a List object. In this example, the Print
>   method is used to display the contents of the list to the console. In
>   addition, the C# example also demonstrates the use of anonymous
>   methods to display the contents to the console. Note that the example
>   does not explicitly declare an Action variable. Instead, it passes
>   a reference to a method that takes a single parameter and that does
>   not return a value to the List.ForEach method, whose single
>   parameter is an Action delegate. Similarly, in the C# example, an
>   Action delegate is not explicitly instantiated because the
>   signature of the anonymous method matches the signature of the
>   Action delegate that is expected by the List.ForEach method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<String> names = new List<String>();
        names.Add("Bruce");
        names.Add("Alfred");
        names.Add("Tim");
        names.Add("Richard");

        // Display the contents of the list using the Print method.
        names.ForEach(Print);

        // The following demonstrates the anonymous method feature of C# 
        // to display the contents of the list to the console.
        names.ForEach(delegate(String name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        });

        names.ForEach(name =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        });
    }

    private static void Print(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
/* This code will produce output similar to the following:
 * Bruce
 * Alfred
 * Tim
 * Richard
 * Bruce
 * Alfred
 * Tim
 * Richard
 */
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach(var itemToAdd in add)
{
   Do_first_thing(itemToAdd);
   Do_Second_Thing(itemToAdd);
}
```

or if you will insist on using the `ForEach` method on `List<>`

```
add.ForEach(itemToAdd  => 
{
   Do_first_thing(itemToAdd);
   Do_Second_Thing(itemToAdd);
});
```

Personally I'd go with the first, it's clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you don't need to do things this way. Just use a plain `foreach`:

```
foreach (var question in problem.Questions)
{
    question.AssignedDate = DateTime.Now;
    _uow.Questions.Add(question);
}
```

Unless there is specific reason to use a lambda, a `foreach` is cleaner and more readable. As an added bonus it does not force you to materialize the collection of questions into a list, most likely reducing your application's memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Yes on reflection I agree with you. However I had to accept the other answer as this fits best with my question. Thank you for your help / advice.

Answer (score 0):

use a foreach statement

```
foreach (Question q in add)
{
   _uow.Questions.Add(q);
   q.AssignedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

or as astander propose do  `_obj.AssignedDate = DateTime.Now;` in the `.ForEach(` method

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
add.ForEach(_obj =>
                    {
                        _obj.AssignedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        _uow.Questions.Add(_obj);

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add.ForEach(delegate(Question q)
    {
        // This is anonymous method and you can do what ever you want inside it.
        // you can access THE object with q
        Console.WriteLine(q);
    });
```